# Read all data from Serial Com Port

Tags: c++, serial-port

***Introduction:***

I have a device connected to my computer to the serial Port COM3. With the help of the trial version of "Serial Port Monitor" I was able to read out the data the device emits. The output looks something like this: (I reduced it to the needed content)

sorry for the html table, I guess SO isn't made for tables

```html
<table border=1px>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
      <th>Function</th>
      <th>Direction</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Data char</th>
      <th>Data length</th>
      <th>Port</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7765</td>
      <td>07:59:11:235</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>f0 </td>
      <td>≡</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7795</td>
      <td>07:59:11:417</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>fb </td>
      <td>√</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9405</td>
      <td>07:59:21:836</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>f6 ff f6 ff f7 </td>
      <td>÷&nbsp;÷&nbsp;≈</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11045</td>
      <td>07:59:35:641</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>f6 ff f6 </td>
      <td>÷&nbsp;÷</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13815</td>
      <td>07:59:57:720</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>f6 ff f7 </td>
      <td>÷&nbsp;≈</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14005</td>
      <td>07:59:59:160</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>f2 fe f3 ff f3 </td>
      <td>≥■≤&nbsp;≤</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15885</td>
      <td>08:00:15:897</td>
      <td>IRP_MJ_READ</td>
      <td>UP</td>
      <td>STATUS_SUCCESS</td>
      <td>fd f0 </td>
      <td>²≡</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>COM3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***sample Code:***

To use this data in a c++ programm i found following function:

```
int ReadByte(LPCWSTR PortSpecifier) {
DCB       dcb;
int       retVal;
BYTE      Byte = 0;
DWORD     dwBytesTransferred;
DWORD     dwCommModemStatus;

HANDLE hPort = CreateFile(
    PortSpecifier,
    GENERIC_READ,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL
    );
if (!GetCommState(hPort, &dcb)) return 0; //ERROR

dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;          //9600 Baud 
dcb.ByteSize = 8;                 //8 data bits 
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;            //no parity 
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;        //1 stop

if (!SetCommState(hPort, &dcb)) return 0; //ERROR

//SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR);       //receive character event  
SetCommMask(hPort, EV_RXCHAR | EV_TXEMPTY);       //receive character event  

WaitCommEvent(hPort, &dwCommModemStatus, 0);  //wait for character 

if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR)
    ReadFile(hPort, &Byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0);  //read 1 
else if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_ERR)
    retVal = 0x101;
retVal = Byte;
CloseHandle(hPort);
cout << retVal << endl;
return       retVal;}
```

***Problem:***

This works fine, as long as there is only one hexadecimal in the data outout from the device. But as you can see, all the interesting stuff happens with more than just one hexadecimal.

How can I get all the numbers from the output maybe in an array of ints?

This is my first time working with Ports, so it might be really simple and I just don't see it yet.

Comment: I believe you call `ReadFile` (maybe both `WaitCommEvent` and then `ReadFile`) over and over until you decide you don't want to keep reading. You can also read more than one byte at a time if you prefer.

Comment: And how do I read more than just one byte? I guess I should read up to 6 bytes at once

Comment: just provide buffer large enough to fit more than one byte. for example `BYTE Bytes[6]; ReadFile(hPort, Bytes, 6, &dwBytesTransferred, 0); `

Comment: This is not device data, it looks like diagnostic output from a custom serial port driver.  "IRP_MJ_READ" corresponds to ReadFile(), but on the driver side.  The kind of output that a driver developer would find useful to debug his code.  It is definitely not healthy, it also emits binary data as text and that is not valid in HTML.  You have to get this turned off to get ahead, probably requires some kind of registry key.  Talk to the programmer or support engineer, use a telephone.

Comment: And be a bit cautious.  While there is some evidence that he debugged the driver, this is not a ringing endorsement for anybody testing the driver installer.  You might be the first victim, having a good working relationship with the vendor is important.